# Coffeescript Backbone extends / Class Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am trying to break out some methods that I am using across my backbone models, and I don't understand why it isn't working.

base_class.js.coffee

```
class MyApp.Models.BaseClass extends Backbone.Model

Linked: () =>
  @._linked

Link: (form) =>
  if @._linked == false
    $(form).backboneLink(@, {'prefixed':true})
    @._linked = true
  else
    $(form).backbonePopulate(@, {'prefixed':true})

Dirty: () ->
  @collection.Dirty()
  @._dirty = true

Clean: () ->
  @._dirty = false

isDirty: () =>
  @._dirty
```

page.js.coffee

```
#= require ./base_class

class MyApp.Models.Page extends MyApp.Models.BaseClass

  initialize: () ->
    console.log('Page Object initialized')
    @._dirty = false
    @changes = []
    @.name = 'Page'
    @._linked = false

 url: () ->
    '/pages/' + @id
```

However when I go into the console

```
page = new MyApp.Models.Page();    #=> Page Object initialized
page.Link($('#myform'));   #=>  Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Page> has no method 'Link'
```

I dont understand why the methods aren't being inherited.

Here is a jsfiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9bPX/11/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your indentation is off. Your CoffeeScript looks like this:

```
class MyApp.Models.BaseClass extends Backbone.Model

Linked: () =>
  @._linked
#...
```

but it should look like this:

```
class MyApp.Models.BaseClass extends Backbone.Model

  Linked: () =>
    @._linked
  #...
```

Your lack of indentation gives you an empty `MyApp.Models.BaseClass` and then a bunch of inaccessible functions inside an anonymous object in the JavaScript:

```
// CoffeeScript boilerplate...
MyApp.Models.BaseClass = (function(_super) {
  // Standard CoffeeScript class boilerplate...
})(Backbone.Model);

({
  Linked: function() {
    return _this._linked;
  },
  // etc...
});
```

So fix your indentation in your `MyApp.Models.BaseClass` and you should be fine. Remember that the entire block structure of CoffeeScript is based on the indentation so if you don't have your indentation right then you have a bunch of nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

If your test code is as you posted it <strike>(and the namespace differences on the classes is a pasting mistake)</strike>, the error is that you're not calling the constructor on Page, instead you're making a reference to it:

```
page = new MyApp.Models.Page;
```

should be

```
page = new MyApp.Models.Page();
```

Check it out here (open a console):

http://jsfiddle.net/Y9bPX/3/

Comment: any Ideas?  I think I am going to open an issue with backbone

Comment: The parentheses when calling `new` are optional in both JavaScript and CoffeeScript.